# Creating a temporary name for a button

Tags: c#, windows

I've been looking for a solution for days now.
Currently have 2 `Forms`. Main `Form` has multiple buttons, lets say (1-10).
 All buttons will open up my 2nd `Form` (say I press `Button` 4). On my 2nd `Form` I have a `ComboBox` with different names and a confirm button. When I choose a name from the `ComboBox`, then press the confirm button.

I want the name selected in the `ComboBox` to be displayed as the new button text from my `Main` form (So `name3` from `Form` 2 `ComboBox` will replace `Button` text (`Button` 4) on Main `Form`).

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

- I can get the text from `ComboBox` to Main `Form` into a `Label` or a `Button` of my choosing, but I can't do it from the pressed button on Main `Form` which opened `Form` 2.
- I've tried changing the button pressed on Main `Form` to a `buttonTemp` name, then letting the text from `ComboBox` change `buttonTemp` text, but it's coming up as it doesn't exist on `Form` 2.

`Form` 1 code:

```
public void b1111_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b1111.BackColor = Color.Red;
    buttonTemp.Name = "bTemp2";
    b1111.Name = "buttonTemp";

    Classroom f4 = new Classroom();
    f4.Show();
}
```

this is on `Form` 2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    temp1 = comboBox1.Text;

    // trying to figure out the label text
    foreach (Term1 Form1 in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Term1>())
    {
        Form1.buttonTemp.Text = comboBox1.Text; 
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: please post the code that you currently have. It's difficult for someone to suggest a solution when they don't know what your current design is.

Comment: Hi sorry, have just added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not operate on the controls of other forms. Instead operate with values.
In your case when you finished and closed Form2 you can return a value back to the Form1 and update button text with a returned value.

In Form2 create public property which will be populated before you close Form2.

```
public string SelectedName { get; set; }

private void selectNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectedName = comboBox1.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```

In Form1 use `.ShowDialog()` method to display form in modal form

```
public void openForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openForm2Button.BackColor = Color.Red;

    using (var form = new Classroom())
    {
        form.ShowDialog();
        // next line will be execute after form2 closed

        openForm2Button.Text = form.SelectedName; // update button text
    }
}
```

Suggested by @Enigmativity in the comments:

```
// Form 2
public string SelectedName => comboBox1.Text;

private void selectNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

// Form 1 remains same
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! SOLVED MY PROBLEM! This problem has been doing my head in for days ! Just started learning so was very frustrating but thank you so much!

Comment: I think it would be better to make the property a facade to the control. Right now there's a bit of double-handling of the value.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks - updated answer with your suggestion, which I found better.

Answer (score -1):

There is many ways to get your goal.
I hope you try to use event.

You can make your own event as below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //define listen event from custom event handler
        _form2.OnUserSelectNewText += new Form2.TextChangeHappen(_form2_OnUserSelectNewText);
}
```

When you have member variable for remember which button clicked by user.

```
private Control activeControl = null;
```

and you can get text that user's choice from your custom event at Form2.

```
//to make simple code, centralize all buttons event to here. 
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //to remeber which button is clicked.
        activeControl = (Button)sender;
        _form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

and then you just change text of "activeControl".

```
private void _form2_OnUserSelectNewText(string strText)
{
        activeControl.Text = strText;
}
```

please refer this, how to make custom event with delegate.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //you can expand your own custom event, string strText can be Control, DataSet, etc
    public delegate void TextChangeHappen(string strText); //my custom delegate
    public event TextChangeHappen OnUserSelectNewText;     //my custom event

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // to prevent null ref exception, if there is no event handler.
        if (OnUserSelectNewText != null) 
        {
            OnUserSelectNewText(this.comboBox1.Text);
        }

        this.Close();
    }
}
```